# Providing css class to the excel cell using ExcelExportCellFormatting event of radgid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have an issue with my radgrid in the asp.net application. When exporting the grid data to excel i need to add few styles to specific cells. For the purpose i used ExcelExportCellFormatting event of radgrid.

```
   Protected Sub RadGrid1_ExcelExportCellFormatting(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.ExcelExportCellFormatting

     If <condition> Then
         e.Cell.Style("background-color") = Red
     End If
   End Sub
```

This code is working fine. But I what to replace the e.Cell.Style("background-color") = Red with giving a css to that cell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this in two simple steps:

1) Add the body of the desired CSS class in the HTMLExporting handler

```
protected void RadGrid1_HTMLExporting(object sender, GridHTMLExportingEventArgs e)
{
    string myClass = ".myClass { ...declaration... }";
    e.Styles.Append(myClass);
}
```

2) Set this CSS class to the desired cells at ExportCellFormatting event

```
protected void RadGrid1_ExportCellFormatting(object sender, ExportCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cell.CssClass = "myClass";
}
```

This code needs a newer version of RadControls. It is possible to do the same with an older version but the code will be a bit different because these two events has been added in some of the recent versions.